inside of pom.xml update the snapshot version using azure devops pipeline
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - script: |
        #!/bin/bash
        increment_version() {
            current_version=$1
            major=$(echo "$current_version" | cut -d '.' -f1)
            minor=$(echo "$current_version" | cut -d '.' -f2)
            minor=$((minor + 1))
            if [ $minor -gt 9 ]; then
                major=$((major + 1))
                minor=0
            fi
            echo "$major.$minor"
        }
        update_pom_xml() {
          pom_file="$1"
          ver=$(grep -oP '<version>\K[^<]*' "$pom_file" | grep 'SNAPSHOT' | sed 's/-SNAPSHOT//')
          if [ -n "$ver" ]; then
              echo "Updating version in $pom_file"
              new_version=$(increment_version "$ver")
              echo "ver: $ver"
              echo "new_version: $new_version"
              updated_pom_content=$(sed "s|<version>$ver-SNAPSHOT</version>|<version>$new_version-SNAPSHOT</version>|g" "$pom_file")
              echo "updated_pom_content: $updated_pom_content"
              echo "$updated_pom_content" > "$pom_file"
              echo "Version updated in $pom_file to $new_version-SNAPSHOT"
              echo "$pom_file" >> updated_poms.txt
          fi
        }
        updated_pom_count=0
        while IFS= read -r -d '' pom_file; do
            update_pom_xml "$pom_file"
            ((updated_pom_count++))
        done < <(find . -type f -name 'pom.xml' -print0)

        echo "Total updated pom.xml files: $updated_pom_count"

        # Set user information
        git config --global user.email "venturingdigitally@gmail.com"
        git config --global user.name "venturing digitally"

        # Add, commit, and push changes
        git branch -a
        git checkout investigation/unit_test_implementation_pipeline
        git add .
        git commit -m "Update pom.xml files"  
        git diff
        git push origin investigation/unit_test_implementation_pipeline  # Replace "master" with your branch name if different
      displayName: 'Update and Push pom.xml files'

This is my version update code. How to push that code to my Azure DevOps repo using pipeline?

I tested the following yaml in my pipeline, and your "Add, commit, and push changes" code is correct.
The thing you need to do is to give your build service account the Git 'GenericContribute' permission in project settings -> repositories -> security. You can also search the identity ID (the xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx in the error message) to find the build service account you are using.

Otherwise, you may get the error

remote: TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx', scope 'repository'.

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - script: |
        # Generate a new pom.xml to pretend I updated the pom.xml
        echo "update pom.xml files" >>pom.xml

        # Set user information
        git config --global user.email "test@test.com"
        git config --global user.name "test"

        # Add, commit, and push changes
        git branch -a
        git checkout main
        git pull
        git add .
        git commit -m "Update pom.xml files"  
        git diff
        git push origin main # Replace your branch name if different
      displayName: 'Update and Push pom.xml files'

Test result:


After adding Git pull:


that's not work i am facing  again same error
: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/venturingdigitally/Qssence/_git/Qssence-Backend'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Hi @SʜɩvʌŋsʜTʜʌĸʋʀ, this is because someone made changes to the branch after you check out the branch. You can add a git pull  after the git checkout main to get the latest update on the branch.  I have updated my answer with   git pull.

Hi @SʜɩvʌŋsʜTʜʌĸʋʀ, can the git pull help with the issue?
